# Create a X509Certificate2 object using PEM with password in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I really don't understand how certificates work and can't find much information on how to create a [X509Certificate2 object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=net-6.0) in .NET Framework. I need the certificate object so that I can add it to an Http handler. I have three items: a cert.pem file, a key.pem file and a password that I provided when I created the files. The files where generated from running this command:

```
> "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\openssl.exe" req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -sha256 -days 365
```

The console then asked me to provide a "PEM pass phrase" and I entered it. Now I was able to create a X509Certificate2 object in .NET 6, but cannot find a way to do the same in .NET Framework.

This code works in .NET 6, but I have no idea how to do the same thing in .NET Framework 4.6.1.

```cs
    public static X509Certificate2 CreateCertificate(string publicCert, string privateCert, string password = @"P@ssw0rd1")
    {
        byte[] publicPemBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(publicCert);
        using var publicX509 = new X509Certificate2(publicPemBytes);
        var privateKeyBlocks = privateCert.Split("-", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKeyBlocks[1]);

        RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
        if (privateKeyBlocks[0] == "BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY")
        {
            rsa.ImportFromEncryptedPem(privateCert, password);
        }

        X509Certificate2 keyPair = publicX509.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa);
        return keyPair;
    }
```

The variable `publicCert` has the raw value of the cert.pem file (the one that start with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`. The variable `privateCert` has the raw value of the key.pem file (the one that start with `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----`.

Comment: You cannot. PEM support is solely in .NET Core. To load certificates from PEM files on .NET Framework, you need third party libraries like Bouncy Castle.

Comment: @LexLi Great! Any code snippets for how to use Bouncy Castle?

Comment: That has been discussed for more than a decade, so ask search engines.

Comment: "I  really don't understand how certificates work" Maybe that is the real first step you should work on? It would certainly allow you to avoid lots of problems in the future from simple "not working"  cases to more serious one of security breaches. Certificates are no magic, once you split the real technical stuff from all the marketing fluff, and once you understand asymmetrical encryption, certificates are a no brainer.